# Postman Two endpoints of the same controller are returning the same response

Tags: c#, .net, http, postman

In Postman if i run one of the endpoints in my controller, then it shows me the correct response. But then when I call the other endpoint, it shows the same response as the first one.

Someone mentioned that it may be because I am calling the service multiple times.

How can I fix this? Should I make separate service for these endpoints even though that would be bad design since they use the same function?

This is my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
{AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks() {
  var projects = await _taskService.GetTasks(Constants.CleanNameSuffix, Constants.CleanNameRegex);
  var dashboard = new DashboardDto{
    Projects = projects
  }
  return Ok(dashboard);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("clean")]
{AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCleanTasks() {
  var projects = await _taskService.GetTasks(Constants.NameSuffix, Constants.NameRegex);
  var dashboard = new DashboardDto{
    Projects = projects
  }
  return Ok(dashboard);
}
```

Comment: Can you run the code locally? if so, put a breakpoint on both endpoints and see if the postman request hit either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpGet` function takes in the route; I think this is a better practice.

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetString([FromRoute]string id)
        {
            return Ok(id);
        }

        [HttpGet("MyFileName/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFileName([FromRoute]string id)
        {
            return Ok($"{id}.xlsx"));
        }
```